# Scaling multiple factors in a produce calculation when the result is scaled

Tags: algebra-precalculus

### Problem

I have three percentages $a$, $b$ and $c$ that I am multiplying together to calculate the product $x$.

Now $x$ get scaled down, let's say by a factor of 5. How do I calculate new values for $a$, $b$ and $c$?

### Sandbox

I played around with this numerically to try and get my head round it, but struggled. Let  $a$, $b$, $c$ equal 10, 20 and 30. $x$ is therefore 6000 to begin with.

Let's start with dividing $x$ by 5, so $x'$ is now 1200.

If I flat divide $a$, $b$ and $c$ by 5, I get 2, 4 and 6, the product of which is 48. However, interestingly, I observed that if I multiple 48 by $5^2$, I get 1200, and if I multiply 48 by $5^3$, I get 6000.

However, I am struggling with the underlying algebra here: If $abc=x$, but then we divide the right hand side of the equation by 5, what operation do I need to perform on the left hand side to generate the new values for $a$, $b$ and $c$? My initial thought was that it would be divide by five also, but I'm clearly missing a step here.

NB to confirm, I understand that $(abc)/5$ is not the same as $a/5 \cdot b/5 \cdot c/5$, and the immediate thing to do on the left hand side would be to divide that side by 5 also.

Comment: Maybe
$$
x = abc \Rightarrow \frac{1}{5}x = \frac{1}{5}abc = \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}} a\right)}_{\text{new }a} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}} b\right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}c\right)
$$

Comment: This is really good, and exactly what I'm after. However, what algebraic step requires the cube root to be introduced? (I'm struggling to "see" how the 1/5abc step gets expanded to the three terms in the final step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 
$$
x = abc
$$
leads to
$$
\underbrace{\frac{1}{5}x}_{=x'} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{5}abc}_{=a' b' c'}
$$
If we want to change the three factors $a, b$ and $c$ so that their relative proportions remain the same, we have to replace $a$ with $a'$ , $b$ with $b'$ and $c$ with $c'$ and we want
$$ a' = ka $$
$$ b' = kb $$
$$ c' = kc $$
for some real valued constant $k$. Note that now the relative proportions remain the same, because, for example, $\frac{a'}{b'} = \frac{ka}{kb} = \frac{a}{b}$. So now we have
$$
\frac{1}{5}x = \frac{1}{5}abc = a' b' c' = (ka)(kb)(kc) = k^3 abc
$$
We see that $\frac{1}{5} = k^3 \Rightarrow k = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}$ and then indeed
$$
\frac{1}{5} x = a' b' c' = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}} a \right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}} b \right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}} c\right) = \frac{1}{5}abc
$$